# Can excessive Vitamin D cause insomnia or damage sleep patterns?

Tags: nutrition, sleep, side-effects, sleep-cycles

It seems its well known that low vitamin D can cause sleeping issues, one link:

https://examine.com/nutrition/can-supplemental-vitamind-improve-sleep/

Therefore, I became curious and was wondering about the reverse. If someone had, say, by supplementation (since it seems its nearly impossible to do its via the sun) too much vitamin D. Can that affects someones sleep pattern?

My theory is that vitamin D is correlated with being in the sun. So if your body has too much vitamin D it would think its in the sun to much and stay awake or not have normal sleep patterns. Though I am just guessing. I'd love to see better thought out reasonings and ideally any real scientific evidence pointing to what the relation of **excess** vitamin D with sleep is.

---

By excess vitamin D3 I mean more than 2,000 IU units daily or more than 50,000 IU weekly.

Comment: A note on calcium and magnesium https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/releases/163169.php

Comment: If one is on "high dose" vitamin D, calcium needs will go down (say no more than 500mg a day), but magnesium needs will go up, reserve 100mg magnesium just to assist the Vitamin D. Might not be a bad idea to take K2 also.

Comment: Be under the care of a doctor so they can run regular blood tests, for one thing to check calcium that is in the blood. Kidney issues. Of course vitamin D status. The vitamin K, K2 must be managed with those on blood thinners. So really this should be under physician management imo. https://vitamindwiki.com/Is+50+ng+of+vitamin+D+too+high%2C+just+right%2C+or+not+enough

Comment: Such a person as you describe may be low on magnesium. (It is possible to take more calcium if one is on K2 probably). Again work with a physician who can help monitor a  blood tests. One does not want too much calcium to lodge in the heart, kidneys etc.

Comment: Magnesium education:  http://www.magnesiumeducation.com/

Comment: 50,000 IU weekly should definitely be supervised by a doctor imo. And even with 2000 iu D3 daily I would suggest ingest 100mg (elemental) magnesium a day too. Note: the 100mg magnesium is in addition to the RDA.

Comment: @Gordon just for the record, the person is fictional. I came up with the numbers according to what seems to be the minimum higher dose than doctors recommend. So I was curious how high vitamin D intake can result in bad quality sleep.

Comment: @Gordon you linked to magnesium articles. Is the answer to my question that too much vitamin D absorbs all the magnesium and thus disturbs sleep?

Comment: Yes, I would look to magnesium first. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/28471760/ ;  this I put in just for general interest:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/28471760/

Comment: Vitamin D is going to overwork magnesium. I never said it would absorb all of it.  Many people have less than ideal magnesium status to begin with.

Comment: I am sorry I intended this to be for general interest. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5786912/  I will remove some of these comments later.

Comment: @Gordon no! Don't remove them. I think you can make an answer out of this. Or we can send this to a chat forum, I think your comments are valuable. My question is relation of too much vitamin D with bad sleep and it seems you have a good hypothesis based on data/research.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87162/discussion-between-pinocchio-and-gordon).